# Comparing attributes from the same table using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a contents table and the entires in it are as shown in the attached figure
[image]

There are more than 100,000 entries. I want to fetch the data where the update_date for commit=0 is greater than update_date for commit=1. I also need the corresponding row for commit=1. 
I tried a few things, but takes a long time to retrieve the results. What is the best SQL query I can use. I am using MySQL database.

**EDIT**

I have now updated the table. There is an attribute called content_id which binds the rows together. 
A query like this gives me half of what I want

```
select a.* from contents a, contents b where
a.content_id=b.content_id and
a.update_date > b.update_date and
a.committed=0 and b.committed=1
```

I also want the corresponding entries from committed=1, but they should be appended at the bottom as rows and not vertically concatenated as columns.

For example, I cannot use

```
select * from contents a, contents b where
a.content_id=b.content_id and
a.update_date > b.update_date and
a.committed=0 and b.committed=1
```

because the results from 'b' are appended vertically. Also, is there a better way to write this query. This works really slow if there are many entries in the database.

Comment: Can you provide an example on SQLFiddle? It's difficult to tell exactly what you are looking for with this description alone.

Comment: That is not making sense to me.

Comment: Without having a column that actually binds the `committed` values together,(e. g. something like a `postId`) it is not possible to write a meaningful query. The sequence number `id` is helpful and necessary to identify the event only but not sufficient for applying your query.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in the above example, you only need id=2 as for content id = 1, the update_date for commit=0 is greater than update_date for commit=1 and in that case you need data for commited = 1.

I an using Oracle, so you need to find a suitable replacement for row_number() funtion in mysql.

The logic would be

1. Create a view on the existing table to use rownumber so it will give rownumber like below order by time desc (see if you use a nested query to do it)

   ```
        ID, CONTENT_ID, COMMITED, UPDATE_DATE, ROWN
       2   1   1   06-SEP-15 00:00:56  1
       1   1   0   07-SEP-15 00:00:56  2
       3   2   0   03-SEP-15 00:00:56  1
       4   2   1   04-SEP-15 00:00:56  2
   ```
2. Now select only rows where  where rown=1 and commited=1

This is the query in oracle. The second with query c2 will be your view.

Oracle query

```
         with c1 (id, content_id,commited,update_date) as
         (
             select 1,1,0,sysdate from dual union
             select 2,1,1,sysdate-1 from dual union
             select 3,2,0,sysdate-4 from dual union
             select 4,2,1,sysdate-3 from dual 
         ),
            c2 as 
            (select c1.*,row_number() over(partition by content_id order by update_date) as rown from c1)
            select id,content_id,commited,update_date from c2
            where rown=1 and commited=1
                     ID, CONTENT_ID, COMMITED, UPDATE_DATE, ROWN
```

Output

```
         ID, CONTENT_ID, COMMITED, UPDATE_DATE  
            2   1   1   06-SEP-15 00:06:17
```